# Replacing a Div With Jquery - Screen Moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show, show-hide

I want to change my div content on the click of a link, this currently works by using an id to show hide the div on content.

However the screen moves to the top of the clicked div - I am aware thats because its linked to moving to the location of the id, is there a way that no matter how far the user has scrolled down the page when they are able to click that the screen won't shift to the top of the div?

HTML

```
<li><a href="www.example.com/cakes.php#wedding-tab" onClick="showhide('wedding')" title="Wedding Cakes" class="tabs" id="wedding-tab">Wedding Cakes</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.example.com/cakes.php#celebration-tab" onClick="showhide('birthday')" title="Birthday Cakes" class="tabs" id="celebration-tab">Birthday Cakes</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://www.example.com/cakes.php#christening-tab" onClick="showhide('christening')"title="Christening Cakes" class="tabs" id="christening-tab">Christening Cakes</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://www.example.com/cakes.php#cupcakes-tab" onClick="showhide('occassion')"title="Occassion Cakes" class="tabs" id="cupcakes-tab">Occasion Cakes</a></li>


<div id="wedding">
content
</div>

<div id="birthday">
content
</div>

<div id="christening">
content
</div>

<div id="occassion">
content
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var h1 = $("#wedding").height();
    var h2 = $("#birthday").height();
     var h3 = $("#christening").height();
     var h4 = $("#occassion").height();
    $("#wedding,#birthday,#christening,#occassion").height(Math.max(h1, h2, h3, h4));
    $("#birthday").hide();
    $("#christening").hide();
    $("#occassion").hide();
});

$("#wedding-tab").live('click', function() {
    $("#wedding").show();
    $("#birthday").hide();
     $("#christening").hide();
      $("#occassion").hide();
});

$("#celebration-tab").live('click', function() {
    $("#wedding").hide();
    $("#birthday").show();
     $("#christening").hide();
      $("#occassion").hide();
 });

$("#christening-tab").live('click', function() {
     $("#wedding").hide();
     $("#birthday").hide();
     $("#christening").show();
     $("#occassion").hide();
});

$("#cupcakes-tab").live('click', function() {
    $("#wedding").hide();
    $("#birthday").hide();
     $("#christening").hide();
      $("#occassion").show();
});
```

Comment: Are any of the posted answers of any use to you? Is your problem solved? If you solved it yourself, or without help from those answers posted, please consider posting your solution in order to better-help future visitors with the same, or similar, problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding prevent default should sort your problem..

eg:

```
$("#wedding-tab").live('click', function(e) {
    $("#wedding").show();
    $("#birthday").hide();
    $("#christening").hide();
    $("#occassion").hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to preventDefault as part of your click event

```
$("#christening-tab").live('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#wedding").hide();
 $("#birthday").hide();
 $("#christening").show();
 $("#occassion").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var h1 = $("#wedding").height();
    var h2 = $("#birthday").height();
     var h3 = $("#christening").height();
     var h4 = $("#occassion").height();
    $("#wedding,#birthday,#christening,#occassion").height(Math.max(h1, h2, h3, h4));

    $("#birthday, #christening, #occassion").hide();
// });

    $("#wedding-tab").live('click', function() {
        $("#wedding").show();
        $("#birthday, #christening, #occassion").hide();
        return false;
    });

    $("#celebration-tab").live('click', function() {
        $("#birthday").show();
        $("#wedding, #christening, #occassion").hide();
        return false;
     });

    $("#christening-tab").live('click', function() {
         $("#christening").show();
         $("#wedding, #birthday, #occassion").hide();
        return false;
    });

    $("#cupcakes-tab").live('click', function() {
          $("#occassion").show();
        $("#wedding, #birthday, #christening").hide();
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

May I show a slightly more concise version of your wall of script:

```
$('li > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.firstChild.nodeValue.toLowerCase().split(/ /)[0];
    $('#' + id).toggle().siblings().not('ul').hide();
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nDjm8/).

This assumes that you only want to show div with the corresponding `id` when you click a link (clicking the 'wedding-tab' link will show the 'wedding' div, and hide the others?

It prevents the default action of the clicked `a`, so the window *shouldn't* move after you click the link.

Also, I fixed a typo in your mark-up, the div `id` was 'occassion':

```
<div id="occassion">
    content
</div>
```

This is wrong, and, far more importantly, inconsistent with your own spelling of the word in the link-text in the `li` element (where it was `Occasion Cakes`). So I fixed the div's misspelling.

Hopefully this is of some use to you.

References:

1. Regular JavaScript:

   - [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/Node.firstChild).
   - [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeValue).
   - [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
   - [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
2. jQuery:

   - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
   - [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
   - [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
   - [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
   - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
   - [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).